# How to change arrow tip in tikz

Tags: latex, tikz

Is there a simple way to increase the size of an arrow tip using something like:

```
\tikzset{myptr/.style=->, ????}
```

without designing a new arrow style from scratch?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

One solution, very quick, to just scale the arrow head is number `%2` in the following:

```latex
\documentclass[multi=false,tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%1
\draw [->,>=stealth] (0,.5) -- (2,.5);
%2
\draw [decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with
    {\arrow[scale=3,>=stealth]{>}}},postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

(sorry for excessive zoom).

Much more in the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf) and in [this answer, that I used as a source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-make-an-arrow-bigger-and-change-its-color-in-tikz/27287#27287).

**Addendum**

`\tikzset` approach. This code:

```latex
\documentclass[multi=false,tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{myptr/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with %
    {\arrow[scale=3,>=stealth]{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
%1
\draw [->,>=stealth] (0,.5) -- (2,.5);
%2
\draw [myptr] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces the same output as the above one (source: [PGF Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), section 2.8).

Obviously you can use `-Latex` instead of `stealth`.

Comment: My original definition is \tikzset{myptr/.style=-latex}. I would like to change it in some simple way because it is used in many places. I tried to change it to something like \tikzset{myptr/.style={-Latex[length=3mm,width=5mm]}} but it produced an error: "I do not know the key 'length[ ...".  BTW my knowledge of tikz is rather poor.

Comment: I prefer just those that use "myptr", if possible.

Comment: is it possible to only to make arrow tips smaller?

Comment: @alper try `\draw [-{Stealth[length=0.3mm, width=0.2mm]}] (0,0.5) -- (1,0.5);` as in my answer below...tune the values in millimeters and let me know ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is a new solution, see https://latexdraw.com/exploring-tikz-arrows/#t-1610685307397. It allows changing both the length and width of arrows:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows}


\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (0,0.5) -- (1,0.5);
  \draw [-stealth] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]